# Удалить некоторые символы в строке JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

Нужно вывести весь объект в виде строки, но в таком формате, чтобы не было скобок которые автоматически создаются.

Вот объект:

```
crd = {};

crd[2] = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100
}
crd[3] = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200
}
```

Вывожу:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(crd));
```

Получается:

```
{"2":{"x":200,"y":200},"3":{"x":100,"y":100}}
```

Мне нужно чтобы было так:

```
2 200 200 3 100 100
```

То есть убрать символы `{`, `}`, `"`, `x`, `y` и `:`, и вывести четкий текст с цифрами. Подскажите, как это сделать? Может быть есть способ лучше?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет гарантии в каком порядке будут выведены ключи, то есть `x` и `y` будут перепутаны в общем случае

я бы сделал так:

```js
crd = {};

crd[2] = {
  y: 100,
  x: 100
}
crd[3] = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(crd))

console.log(Object.keys(crd).map(function(k) { 
  return k + ' ' + crd[k].x + ' ' + crd[k].y
}).join(' '))
```

Comment: Аха, а у меня не поднялась рука конкатенацию мапить, reduce наваял)

Comment: @vp_arth я решил что reduce тут это слишком

Comment: Порядок x и y к сожалению важен. Действительно ли есть возможность сбоя? Как избежать этого?

Comment: я изменил ответ, чтобы был неправильный вывод в первом `console.log`, вообще это не специфицировано, но пока-что всегда я наблюдаю только такое поведение - какой порядок вставки ключей в объект такой и порядок вывода

Comment: Если вставлять в определенном порядке - проблем не будет?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда, вы же вручную задаёте порядок вывода в `k + ' ' + crd[k].x + ' ' + crd[k].y`. Проблемы могут возникнуть только при автоматической сериализации (stringify)

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда не должно, но лучше на это не полагаться

Comment: Подскажите, а что такое k => k ?

Comment: это стрелочная функция, сейчас поменяю на обычную, чтобы было понятно

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Неясно, как решать задачу в общем виде, потому что непонятно, например, чем ключи x/y хуже ключей 2/3.
Поэтому, решим в частном виде.
Предположим, что нужные данные - это числа:

```js
const crd = {};

crd[2] = {
  x: 100,
  y: 101
}
crd[3] = {
  x: 200,
  y: 201
}
crd[5] = {
  y: 301,
  x: 300
}

let result = JSON.stringify(crd)
   .split(/\D+/) // Разбиваем строку на числовые элементы
   .filter(a=>a) // Отбрасываем пустые элементы(в начале и конце)
   .join(' ');  // Собираем итоговую строку
console.log(result)

// Предположение, что структура жёстко задана({key: {x, y}})
let res2 = Object.keys(crd)
  .reduce((res, key) => {
    res.push(key);
    ['x', 'y'].forEach(k => res.push(crd[key][k]));
    return res;
  }, [])
  .join(' ');
console.log(res2);
```

Comment: а ведь нет гарантии в каком порядке будут выведены ключи, то есть `x` и `y` будут перепутаны в общем случае

Comment: Добавил решение на базе жёсткой структуры объекта.

Answer (score 0):

`.match(/\d+/g)` — ищет совпадения через регулярное выражение и возвращает массив. `\d` — одна цифра. А плюсик после него означает "одно или несколько совпадений". Флажок `g` - (global), позволяет найти все совпадения, а не остановиться на первом найденном.

А из полученного массива собираем строку через `.join()` - поставив один пробел между элементами.

```js
crd = {
  2: {x: 100, y: 100},
  3: {x: 200, y: 200}
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(crd).match(/\d+/g).join(' ') );
```

*Если там могут быть и нецелые числа, тогда `\d+\.*\d*` — звездочка означает "ноль раз или больше"

Comment: Спасибо, в данном случае вероятность перестановки x и y исключается?

Comment: @Евгений Калайда нет, такая история сработает правильно только при условии, что жестко задается везде, сперва x, потом y... Соседние ответы учитывают еще случай, если перепутать и записать сперва y, потом x.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать что означает match(/\d+/g) в данном случае?

Comment: Эмм... `match()` вообще используется, чтобы найти какие-то ключевые символы в тексте (строке). Он слева направо по очереди ищет числа, не разбирая, там вообще x или y. И в этом случае возвращает массив `[2, 100, 100, 3, 200, 200]` —